# Building or downloading a jQuery file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying build a menu using a tutorial I found on Google. Everything is straight forward but I can't build or download the jQuery file.

The tutorial I am working with is [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-os-x-style-dock-and-stack-navigation/).

I am doing the first part of the tutorial 'jQuery OS X Dock #1 (Horizontal)' and its 3 steps in.

Here is the part I can't get right.

> The JavaScript
>   We’ll bring in our JavaScript files now starting with jQuery 1.3.2. The fisheye-iutil.min.js file is the combination of the Fisheye plugin and its dependent iutil.js file. We’ll create the last file and put our JavaScript necessary to initialize the dock in it.
>
> 1) %MINIFYHTML80326fa6f009adb1c85139aad3bf695d10%

Could someone show me how to build this file there talking about or how to reference it or something?

Answer (score 0):

Might be this file:

[fisheye-iutil.min.js](http://code.google.com/p/cssdock/downloads/detail?name=fisheye-iutil.min.js)

Strange though that nobody else noticed that problem in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

from looking at the example, you can take it directly from [Fisheye-iutil.min.js](http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/358_jquery/example%20files/js/fisheye-iutil.min.js)